# Need to compare two ArrayLists, but keep hitting exception because one is printing horizontally

Tags: java, arrays, selenium

I have two array lists. I need to compare them using assertion, however when I print my array list, one is vertical consisting of 12 objects, and the other is horizontal, with all 12 objects on the same line. When I compare them, I get get an exception. One of the lists consists of time values being pulled from a website, and the other is an array list I created that increments 2 hours based on the current time. Both lists, should match. However, I don't see what the mistake is here. Ideally, my array list that I created based on local time should match the vertical one I pulled from the website. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Here is the full code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;


public class TestScenario extends BasePage {

    @Test
    public void testOne() throws InterruptedException {

//        Navigate to website
        navigateToUrl("https://www.darksky.net/");

        ArrayList timeNow = new ArrayList();

//        Create list of WebElements returned by xpath
        List<WebElement> elements = getDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"timeline\"]/div/div[3]"));

//        For loop to print list of elements
        for (WebElement s1 : elements) {
            timeNow.add(s1.getText().toUpperCase());
        }

//        Date format to print time in hours and AM/PM
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ha");
        String time = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

//        Calendar object to return date
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(new Date());

//        Array created for expected time values
        ArrayList timeExpected = new ArrayList();
        timeExpected.add("NOW");

//        Do while loop to add 2 hours to current time 12 times (24hrs) which is returned from calendar object
        int addHours = 2;
        int counter = 0;
        do {
            cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, addHours);

        counter += 1;

        timeExpected.add(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));

    } while (counter < 11);

//        For loops to print all time expected results added to array from do while loop
    System.out.println(timeNow);
    System.out.println(timeExpected);

    Assert.assertEquals(timeNow, timeExpected);


}
```

Here is the output:

```
[NOW
5AM
7AM
9AM
11AM
1PM
3PM
5PM
7PM
9PM
11PM
1AM]
[NOW, 5AM, 7AM, 9AM, 11AM, 1PM, 3PM, 5PM, 7PM, 9PM, 11PM, 1AM]

java.lang.AssertionError: lists don't have the same size expected [12] but found [1]
Expected :12
Actual   :1
```

Comment: you should try to print elements.size() and see if it is 1 or what you expect

Comment: Debug your code and check whether your lists are equal or not. Pto tip: They aren't.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
List<WebElement> elements = getDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"timeline\"]/div/div[3]"));
```

is returning only one WebElement whose text value is :

```
NOW
5AM
7AM
9AM
11AM
1PM
3PM
5PM
7PM
9PM
11PM
1AM
```

Since array size is not matching you are getting the AssertionError.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that

```
List<WebElement> elements = getDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"timeline\"]/div/div[3]"));
```

is returning only one element which is:
`NOW
5AM
7AM
9AM
11AM
1PM
3PM
5PM
7PM
9PM
11PM
1AM`

So try changing your separation condition.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are right at pointing the issue, To solve this please add the below lines

```
    WebElement element = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"timeline\"]/div/div[3]"));
    List<String> timeNow = Arrays.asList(element.getText().toUpperCase().split("\\s+"));
```

Instead of this

```
         ArrayList timeNow = new ArrayList();

//        Create list of WebElements returned by xpath
        List<WebElement> elements = getDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"timeline\"]/div/div[3]"));

//        For loop to print list of elements
        for (WebElement s1 : elements) {
            timeNow.add(s1.getText().toUpperCase());
        }
```